# Troubles importing inner class into main activity on Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Android app that makes use of AsyncTask to download some data. To make my code a bit more readable I re-created this code on a separate class ("ContentManager"). However, I don't know how to import it into my main activity.

Here's the code on my main activity, which doesn't work (error: "Cannot resolve symbol DownloadJson"):

```
public class MyApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_list);

        ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager();
        ContentManager downloadJsonTask = new contentManager.DownloadJson();

        downloadJson.execute("http://.../api/...");

    }
}
```

And here's my AsyncTask code, that lives in a class file (ContentManager.java on the same package folder than the main activity):

```
public class ContentManager {

    // DownloadJson is a class that gets a JSON response given a url specified on the call
    public class DownloadJson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Defined required variables
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            // Try to download content
            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char currentCharacter = (char)data;

                    result += currentCharacter;

                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I import an inner class from another file? Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, i'm old :)

The problem is with your declaration of DownloadJson class. 
Simply because it is non static inner class.

And as such it requires you to provide outer class reference to create an instance.

So forcing our way to simply create instance is:

```
DownloadManager dm = new DownloadManager();
dm.new DownloadJson ();
// But this is simply ridiculous right?
```

The proper way is to add static to your DownloadJson class

```
public static class DownloadJson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
```

And with that usage is much simpler:

```
DownloadJson json = new ContentManager.DownloadJson();
```

---

So the last thing is to say why, and what actually happens :)

There are two ways to declare inner class

1 - Non static

```
public class A { 
    int value;
    public class B {
    }
}
```

The B class hold an reference to upper class and as such it needs to be created from class A, or to be created with class A reference (as context), declaring our inner class this ways makes possible to access any non static method, variable or  type of upper class as if u would normally in upper class. So writing this code is correct inside B class

```
void setUpperValue() {
    value = 30; 
}
```

2 - Static

```
public class A {
    int value;
    public static class B {
    }
}
```

The B class hold no reference to upper class and us such does not need any additional context to create however it cannot access to local (non static variables). 
So invoking inside class B:

```
value = 20;
```

Will make compile time error

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

`ContentManager.DownloadJson downloadJsonTask = contentManager.new DownloadJson();`

Comment: I tried ContentManager$DownloadJson() downloadJson = new ContentManager$DownloadJson(); but it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, this does not apply to you. You should call `ContentManager.DownloadJson downloadJsonTask = contentManager.new DownloadJson();`

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 solutions:
1. You can create method in ContentManager to create the instance of DownloadJson class.

```
public DownloadJson createDownloadJson()
{
    return new DownloadJson();
}
```

2. You can create DownloadJson as static class. After that you can create new instance of DownloadJson in MyApp class using this snippet
`DownloadJson downloadJson = new ContentManager.DownloadJson()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead this line

`ContentManager downloadJsonTask = new contentManager.DownloadJson();`

use this

`ContentManager.DownloadJson downloadJsonTask = contentManager.new DownloadJson();`

It should works fine.

Here is some more about nested class (for example how create a static nested class or inner class): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html